# Abbreviation of code in c++

Tags: c++

I have code like this:

```
myMAP.cha.find(1)->second.print();
```

I want to use an abbreviation like this:

```
myMapprn(1)
```

Is there any way to do this and simplify the code?

Comment: Wrap in a function or macro ?

Comment: Yes, introduce a helper function.

Comment: What is wrong with just typing it in? Will help with maintenance in the future. Otherwise a inline helper function

Comment: I'm with @EdHeal, what's actually wrong with typing it? Anything else just obfuscates what the code does, and makes it harder to read.

Comment: If it's a common enough idiom, then yea just inline function, but please give it a more descriptive name. And probably it should be something more like `FindAndPrint(myMAP, 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just making a function that takes `myMAP` and the key:

```
void printKey(const MAP& myMAP, int key) {
  myMAP.cha.find(key)->second.print();
}
```

Now you just call `printKey(myMAP, 1)`. Of course, I don't know what the actual types and variable names should be.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It should be, but they didn't ask for that. ;)